# Access to Ubuntu

Tags: downloads

I am a novice, so need simple instructions. I downloaded Ubuntu online to see if it could replace my current Windows XP, but when restarted, Windows XP starts, not Ubuntu.

How do I use Ubuntu, and how do I get this to use and English keyboard?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details about what you've done and the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

It is normally relatively easy to replace your Microsoft XP operating system with Ubuntu.

1. Download the image to your computer.  I take it your have already completed this.
2. Run an MD5Sum on the download.  See this web site https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
3. If you have a match then you have a good download.
4. You must make a bootable CD/DVD/flash drive.  Merely copying the image is not sufficient.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto
5. Make sure you burn the ISO at the lowest possible speed.  This will increase the chance that you will get a good burn.
6. After you have that completed reboot the computer changing the BIOS to boot first from the CD/DVD or flash drive.  Take care if using a flash drive because some are recognized as additional hard drives so you will have to move it to the front of the boot sequence.  Save and continue with the boot.
7. I would recommend that you try Ubuntu first without making any changes to your system to insure that everything works.  Once you are satisfied go ahead and install after backing up all of your data to an outside device because it will be over-written.
8. Enjoy the experience.